# What is the depression between bridge of nose and brow called?

Tags: human-anatomy

In a human being, what is the depression often found between the bridge of the nose and the brow called?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nasion [New Latin nāsion : nas(o)- + Greek -ion, diminutive suff.] is the region below glabella , also known as the bridge of the nose.

[image: Nasion]

> The nasion is the midline bony depression between eyes where the frontal and two nasal bones meet, just below the glabella.It is one of the skull landmarks, craniometric points for radiological or anthropological skull measurement.

Source:https://radiopaedia.org/articles/nasion